# Javascript canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a javascript canvas using an external javascript file. but for some reason when I run my code instead of getting the canvas I have coded I just get a white block. The chrome debugger finds no problem with my code so I am lost any help would be greatly appriciated.

This is my index file

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Lab1</title> <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/canvas.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600">
                Your browser does not support the canvas tag
            </canvas>
            <p>This is a simple 'Hello World' lab tutorial using the HTML5 canvas.</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And this is my javascript file

```
// check to see if the browser supports 
// the addEventListener function 
if(window.addEventListener) 
{
window.addEventListener 
( 
'Load', // this is the load event 
onLoad, // this is the event handler we are going to write 
false // useCapture boolean value 
);
}

// the window load event handler 
function onLoad() 
{ 
var canvas; 
var context;

// this function will initialise our variables 
function initialise() 
{
    // Find the canvas element using its id attribute. 
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
    // if it couldn't be found 
    if (!canvas) 
    { 
        // make a message box pop up with the error. 
        alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!'); 
        return; 
    }
    // check if there is a getContext function 
    if (!canvas.getContext) 
    { 
        // make a message box pop up with the error. 
        alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!'); 
        return; 
    }
    // Get the 2D canvas context. 
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
    if (!context) 
    { 
        alert('Error: failed to getContext!'); 
        return; 
    }
}

    // this function will actually draw on the canvas 
    function draw() 
    { 
        // set the draw fill style colour to black 
        context.fillStyle = "#000000"; 
        // fill the canvas with black 
        context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 
        // choose a font for our message 
        context.font = "40pt Calibri"; 
        // set the draw fill colour to white 
        context.fillStyle = "#ffffff"; 
        // draw the text at the specified position 
        context.fillText("Hello World!", 150, canvas.height); 
    }
// call the initialise and draw functions 
initialise(); 
draw(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event type needs to be written lowercase: `load`, i.e.

```
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);
```

A list of [available event types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/DOM_event_reference) is referenced for example by Mozilla.

Just a hint: You can set a breakpoint in your `onLoad` function with your Chrome debugger to make sure that it is called by your event listener. It was not and that drew my attention to your `addEventListener` method call.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at that for hours with no luck feel kinda stupid now.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function(){
    // put here your JS code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is important to realize if something doesn't work:

```
window.onload = myFunction;
window.addEventListener("load", myFunction);
```

window.onload, "load"
use lowercase, and don't add "on" to the beginning

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
  // here goes your code
}
```